# Oracle DB can not create Table Showing "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create tables in ORACLE with Foreign Key and Primary key but It is showing me error.
"
        FOREIGN KEY(Branch_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs(Branch_ID),
                                                       *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

```
    FOREIGN KEY(Branch_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs(Branch_ID)
                                                   *
```

ERROR at line 10:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
"

I don't know what is the reason of the error. Please take a look on my sql code.

```
drop table Employees;
drop table Bank_Branchs;
drop table Departments;
drop table Job_Titles;
drop table Accounts;

CREATE TABLE Bank_Branchs(
    Branch_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    Branch_Name VARCHAR2(15),
    Country VARCHAR2(35),
    City VARCHAR2(35),
    Phone VARCHAR2(15),
    Manager_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Branch_ID,Manager_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Departments(
    Dept_ID CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    Head_of_Dept NUMBER(7),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dept_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Job_Titles(
    Title_ID CHAR(3)NOT NULL,
    Title_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    Title_Desc VARCHAR2(250),
    PRIMARY KEY(Title_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Employees
   (Emp_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    Branch_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    Title_ID CHAR(3),
    Department_ID CHAR(3),
    Manager_ID NUMBER(7),
    Salary NUMBER(9),
    Hourly_Rate NUMBER(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Branch_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs(Branch_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Title_ID) REFERENCES Job_Titles (Title_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Department_ID) REFERENCES Departments (Dept_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Manager_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs (Manager_ID)
);





CREATE TABLE Accounts(
    Account_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    Branch_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    Customer_ID NUMBER(7),
    Acc_Type char(2),
    Balance NUMBER(38),
    Rate    NUMBER(9),
    Status VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY(Account_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Branch_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs(Branch_ID)
);
```

I tried to run this using start I:/SQLNAME.sql and the SQL command line is showing me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Tested... And this will work, but please read below...

```
CREATE TABLE Bank_Branchs(
    Branch_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    Branch_Name VARCHAR2(15),
    Country VARCHAR2(35),
    City VARCHAR2(35),
    Phone VARCHAR2(15),
    Manager_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Branch_ID,Manager_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Departments(
    Dept_ID CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    Head_of_Dept NUMBER(7),
    PRIMARY KEY(Dept_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Job_Titles(
    Title_ID CHAR(3)NOT NULL,
    Title_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    Title_Desc VARCHAR2(250),
    PRIMARY KEY(Title_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Employees
   (Emp_ID NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    Branch_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
    Title_ID CHAR(3),
    Department_ID CHAR(3),
    Manager_ID NUMBER(7),
    Salary NUMBER(9),
    Hourly_Rate NUMBER(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Branch_ID, Manager_ID) REFERENCES Bank_Branchs(Branch_ID, Manager_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Title_ID) REFERENCES Job_Titles (Title_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(Department_ID) REFERENCES Departments (Dept_ID)
);
```

It seems like a manager_id would correspond to a employee_id...
It also seems like their may be more than one manager for an individual bank branch..
Bascically, i think manager_id should be removed from bank_branches and this should be created instead:

```
create table bank_branch_managers(
    branch_id number(14),
    manager_id number(7),
    effective_date date,
    activity_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (branch_id, manager_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES Bank_Branches(Brand_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCED Employees( Emp_id) 
 );
```

But you'd need to adjust the setup of "Employees", probably adding a table for managers as well..

Answer (score 0):

A FOREIGN KEY constraint have to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY constraint in another table; or it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

in your bank_branchs table, you have created a composite primary key ie a primary key consisting of more than one column.

```
PRIMARY KEY (Branch_ID,Manager_ID)
```

this statement does not make Brach_ID and Manager_ID as the primary keys, rather it makes their combination as a primary key. and since a foreign key can only refer to either a primary key or a column with UNIQUE constraint, it throws an error.

try adding UNIQUE constraint on both of these columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Bank_Branchs(
Branch_ID NUMBER(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
Branch_Name VARCHAR2(15),
Country VARCHAR2(35),
City VARCHAR2(35),
Phone VARCHAR2(15),
Manager_ID NUMBER(7) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Branch_ID,Manager_ID)
```

);

this might solve your problem.